# Can't find my HDD after installation ubuntu on SSD

Tags: partitioning

I have Ubuntu 22.04 on my 250GB SSD and I have another 1 TB hdd on my laptop but Ubuntu can't find my Hdd. I'm not sure where or how to start finding it.

Comment: hit the `Super` key (left Windows key) and type `Disks`. Should be listed there and you can make a note of the UUID to include it your fstab file.

Comment: I only can find SSD and not showing up HDD

Comment: In the Disks not showing up HDD and only can see SSD.How should I do?

Comment: Before any further troubleshooting check UEFI ("BIOS"). If not recognized there then that is your answer.